# Is it possible to concatenate 3 queries with the && operator?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I have some JavaScript on my page that checks the indexOf to find one of a multitude of strings in my URL, it then performs a function that scrolls to a set position on the page.

I currently am using the following code to concatenate 2 conditions, but I need to incorporate a 3rd condition. When I add an additional line and an additional `&&` my JavaScript fails. Can anyone recommend a better solution?

My current working code:

```
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("search_categories") > -1 && 
        window.location.href.indexOf("search_region") > -1) {
        // do some stuff 
    };
```

The failing code:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("search_categories") > -1 && 
    window.location.href.indexOf("search_region") > -1 && 
    window.location.href.indexOf("upload-a-cv") > -1) {
    // do some stuff 
};
```

Comment: It is possible. I think it fails because the `left condition` failed and it just left there

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `||` instead of `&&` ?

Comment: you can have an many `&&` as you like. if the condition fails it's because the `indexOf` isnt returning a true response

Comment: The only reason that wouldn't work is if your URL doesn't contain those values. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zm9w4L89/

Comment: your code looks ok.  Create 3 temp variables and assign your indexOf expressions each to a variable.  Then use the variables in your if statement.  This is temporary.  It will allow you to debug and break on the variable assignment statements and see what is happening with the values and why the if fails.  You can also check the href value.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? Doesn't do what you expect, or produces some error, or does nothing at all, or...? The code you show tests whether the `location.href` contains *all three* of those strings (as compared to testing whether it contains any of them) - is that what you intend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not call this concatenation. The double ampersand represents the logical AND operator. In general you can have as many operands as possible:

```
operand1 && operand2 && operand3 ...
```

Each `operand` should be, or at least should be evaluated to a boolean value - `true` or `false`. The logical result is applied on the evaluated boolean values as follows:

#### Logical AND ( `&&` )

```
true && true = true
true && false = false
false && true = false
false && false = false
```

This means that if any operand is evaluated to `false`, the whole evaluation is resulting as `false` (`true && true && false` becomes `false` in the end).

In case you want to allow **any** condition (operand) to cause the result to be true, you would have to use the

#### Logical OR ( `||` )

```
true || true = true
true || false = true
false || true = true
false || false = false
```

Effectively `false || false || false || true` evaluates to `true`

If you want to have certain groups of conditions to be all true, and the another group where at least one is true, you have to group them, using braces as in:

-`(true && false) || (false || true)` evaluates to `true`
-`(true && false) && (false || true)` evaluates to `false`

---

In your particular code snippet:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("search_categories") > -1 && 
window.location.href.indexOf("search_region") > -1 && 
window.location.href.indexOf("upload-a-cv") > -1 ) ...
```

it is enough to lack at lease one of the parameters in the request, to have the if expression evaluate to `false`, therefore the body of the `if` statement does not get executed.